# Помогите с регуляркой на поиск целого слова

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно выбрать целые слова состоящие из 6ти символов. Но почему то оно некоторые слова просто режет.
Мое "~\b[а-яёА-ЯЁ]{6}\b~u" почти все выбирает правильно, целое слово из 6ти символов, но некоторые слова режет.
Кусочек кода

```
 if (preg_match_all("~\b[а-яА-Я]{6}\b~u", $contents, $matches)) {
     //some magic
    }
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, текст, с которым регулярное выражение не работает.

Comment: У вас в коде `"~\b[а-яА-Я]{6}\b~u"`  без `ёЁ`

Comment: Почему бы не использовать `[:alpha:]`?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin А зачем, если есть `\p{L}`?

Comment: Или так. Лишь бы не `[а-яА-ЯеЁ]`.

Answer (score -1):

Не хватает флага `g` и букв `ё` и `Ё`. Также можно сократить с помощью флага `i`

```
~\b[а-яё]{6}\b~gui
```

https://regex101.com/r/h7rzfF/1